# Finding outliers via scikit-learn's isolation forest (IF)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, outliers, anomaly-detection

I am trying to detect outliers in my data-set with 5000 observations and 800 features. I have followed the simple steps told in http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_isolation_forest.html

There are some examples in stackoverflow and other sources as well, however, I could not find a decent explanation about the interpretation of outliers returned by isolationforest. First, what I did is:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

X_train = trbb[check_cols]

clf = IsolationForest(n_jobs=6,n_estimators=500, max_samples=256, random_state=23)
clf.fit(X_train)
y_pred_train = clf.predict(X_train)
y_pred_train
```

This returns array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]) where -1's are the outliers.

The shape of `y_pred_train` is 5000, which is identical with `X_train[0]`. So the index of -1 corresponds to the index of X_train. For exp. one of the outlier indices returned by IF is 532. So this means that the point (in 800 dimensional space) in this index is detected as an outlier. After detecting this, how can I approach and use the results to dig more? For example, can I reach the most important features causing the outliers?